# Prevent Coldfusion from encoding html

Tags: html, coldfusion, decode

I am trying to return html from

```
<cfsavecontent variables="html">
 <p>Some html</p>
</cfsavecontent>
<cfreturn html>
```

But when it comes back from the function the html is encoded

I found this thread http://www.coldfusionjedi.com/forums/messages.cfm?threadid=BB31B124-19B9-E658-9D3F5726B8607FD8 which has some solutions but im hoping for something a little less messy. Any help is appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Just to clarify: are you saying that your function returns <p> as &gt;p&lt; ?

Comment: Yes i want to be able to return formatted html to javascript so i can update the innerHTML. When i use <cfset> or <cfsavecontent> the html comes back encoded so "<" becomes "&lt;" when i view the source of the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `returnformat="plain"` in your remote `<cffunction>`.

ColdFusion does not escape HTML automatically. `HtmlEditFormat()` is the function that does that.

However, if you `<cfdump>` the string, then the string will be escaped so that you can see the string in your browser.

Comment: <cfoutput>
  <cfset html = "<p>Some html</p>">
  <cfset html &= "<p>Some other html</p>">
  <cfdump var="#html#">
</cfoutput>

Output//
<p>Some html</p><p>Some other html</p> no luck

Comment: You gotta provide the key details (i.e. it's a remote cffunction) next time... I had to guess it 'cause you said something about innerHTML in the comment. :)

Comment: FYI cfsavecontent works too when i say that returnformat="plain" in the remote function. Thanks again for all the help :)